# Informix equivalent to MySQL 'Replace' command

Tags: mysql, sql, replace, informix

Is there any equivalent command in Informix for [MySQL's  'Replace'](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replace.html) ? I'm just finding references to the string manipulation function.

Thanks!

Comment: Standard SQL's `MERGE` is similar (but more complicated).

Answer (score 1):

Modern versions of Informix (11.70, 12.10) support the [MERGE](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_2030.htm) statement which, I think, can do the job that MySQL `REPLACE` does.  It might require some care coding it correctly.